# PHP: How to populate a page dynamically once the user clicks on the URL

Tags: php, url, dynamic

With help from [@teresko](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/727208/teresko) I've managed to create dynamic pages (& their urls) for my site using the loop below. **My problem is** how do i get the newly created page at `ahref` to combine data I have in database with the template (which I already have ready), so that when the user clicks on it, she/he goes to the page populated with the data. Am i supposed to use a javascript click function (would rather not). How would i do it with php and html?

Here is the loop generating the URLs:

```
<?php foreach ($reciperow as $recipe) { ?>    
    <a href="?id=<?php echo $recipe['uniqno'];?>"><h2><?php echo $recipe['rectitle'];?></h2></a>    
    <p class="subhead"><?php echo $recipe['recsummary']; ?></p>    
<?php } ?>
```

Would really appreciate a solution that stays clear of routing, since my site's a basic project and I plan to get to MVC and PHP routing in the next projects. Thanks.

Comment: AJAX. There is no way to do this purely in PHP. PHP runs entirely on the server side you need client side code (javascript) in order to fetch new data dynamically.

Comment: @ mtinsley, Is there a specific term that is used for this in AJAX - that I may search for it by?

Comment: The snippet you posted above already is a page with a template combining data from the database (assuming `$reciperow` is the result of an SQL query). All you need is to check if the `id=?` is present in `$_GET`, and if so, show that recipe. What does the template that you have ready look like?

Comment: @Kenney the template in this case is the same as the one where the the link is output. So when I click on the link the layout is right, but I wanted to know how exactly to output the full details for the new page  (i know the php that's needed but since all this has to happen on the click or rather the loading of the new page, is this to be treated as a clickevent, or  an onload, and therefore should I use javascript then?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant `How, when user clicks generated link, show him page with data from database accordingly to "id" he/she selected`, then do the following:

```
<?php

    $id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
    if ($id) { // user get here by clicking on link with id

        $data = ... // fetch data from database

?>
        <sometag>Some data from database:<?php echo $data['somecollumn']; ?></sometag>
        ...
<?php

    } else {
        // user just opened first page

        // generate links list as usual
        ...
        foreach ($reciperow as $recipe) {
?>    
            <a href="?id=<?php echo $recipe['uniqno'];?>"><h2><?php echo $recipe['rectitle'];?></h2></a>    
            <p class="subhead"><?php echo $recipe['recsummary']; ?></p>    
<?php
       }

        ...
    }
?>
```

**Edit:**

> Is this how it is normally done for simple sites?

Depends.

If you has only one entity in datadabe, then there will be no arguments clash, `id` is identifier *only* for recipies, but if you intent to show also details for, f.e. ingredients, furniture and/or more, then you must add specificators.

Like, links will look like

```
<a href="?show=recipie&id=<?php echo $recipe['uniqno'];?>">
<a href="?show=ingredient&id=<?php echo $ingredients['id'];?>">
```

... and then data must be fetched and displayed correspondingly:

```
$id = ...;
if ($id)
    switch ($_REQUEST['show']) {
    case 'recipie':
        // show recipie data
        break;
    case 'ingredient':
        // show ingredient data
        break;
    case ...

    default:
        // show start page
    }
```

But with addition of another entities yours `.php` file will grow. Another solution will be to add separate scripts for handling each entity:

```
// generate links list as usual
...
foreach ($reciperow as $recipe) { // look at `recipie.php` portion of link's href
?>    
    <a href="recipie.php?id=<?php echo $recipe['uniqno'];?>"><h2><?php echo $recipe['rectitle'];?></h2></a>    
    <p class="subhead"><?php echo $recipe['recsummary']; ?></p>    
<?php
}
```

And add `recipie.php` file in the same folder as base script with following contents:

```
<?php

    $id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
    if ($id) { // user get here by clicking on link with id

        $data = ... // fetch data from database

?>
        <sometag>Some data from database:<?php echo $data['somecollumn']; ?></sometag>
        ...
<?php

    } else {
?>
        <h1 class="error">No recipie ID specified</h1>
<?php
    }
<?
```

Further exploring will bring you to concepts of `MVC` and `routing` via human-friendly-links format, when links looks like `/home`, `/recipie/12` and/or `/recipie/?id=12` or even `/recipie/12-cream-pie`. But that's story for another time...

Comment: thanks, I guess this should work (took time for me to understand). I guess this will also work since the template used by both the link page and the linked page are the same. Is this how it is normally done for simple sites?